# how to convert canvas image "data:image/jpeg;base64,.." to normal image file - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I have

```
image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1);
```

but this is returning

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDA.......
```

but I need normal image like `src="myimage.png"`

how can I get it from canvas?  i googled a lot, cannot seem to find what i need...

Comment: If you want to convert the base64 string to a file, you have to use a server side language, such as php. If you want to search for it, you'll need Base64 or BLOB as keywords.

Comment: @Cerbrus: I don't think the duplicate you have is quite what the OP was looking for. Here we're posting the base64 code to the server in order to save it to a database. There, it's just figuring out how to download the image client-side.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The string that you're getting *can* be used as the source attribute for an image, you just have to create a new `Image` element to which you can assign it:

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1);
// append image to DOM
```

**EDIT**: Given the comments, you want to turn this into something that be stored in a database. You should `POST` the result of `toDataURL` to your server. Use your server-side technology's IO/image/graphics libraries to decode the base64-encoded part of the data string and write that out to a new file. You can now store that path in your database.

Alternative: just store that whole data string in your database. Then when you render your `<img>` tag you can simply dump it into the `src` attribute:

```
<img src="<< base-64 encoded data string>>" />
```

Comment: this is returning ``data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDA.......`` and NOT imagefile, i want normal file

Comment: Are you looking for how to write a file or how to show that image as an img element?

Comment: That base64 string *is* an image file. Do you mean that you want to have your browser prompt you to download/save an image file?

Comment: @Cory i want to get a file object from this, which i can save into db. is ``image`` in this case an image file?

Comment: What server-side technology are you using?

Comment: @doniyor: Do you _really_ want to store a binary image file in the database? (Hint: you don't). This Base64 string is what you'll want.

Comment: @Cerbrus I _dont_ save binary file of course, i will save the path of file into db and file itself in some directory

Comment: @Cory django in backend

Comment: @Cory the problem with your latest advice is that facebook doesnot crawl inline images, this is the only reason why this whole messup i am doing. ;)